# How to read bytes from NSData

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

Can anyone suggest a method to read bytes from `NSData` (like read function in `@interface` `NSInputStream` : `NSStream`)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can also create an `NSInputStream` from an `NSData` object, if you need the read interface:

```
NSData *data = ...;
NSInputStream *readData = [[NSInputStream alloc] initWithData:data];
[readData open];
```

However, you should be aware that `initWithData` *copies* the contents of data.

Answer (score 27):

[How to read binary bytes in NSData?](https://web.archive.org/web/20130301082816/http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-development/66099-how-to-read-binary-bytes-in-nsdata.html) may help you:

```
NSString *path = @"…put the path to your file here…";
NSData * fileData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile: path];
const char* fileBytes = (const char*)[fileData bytes];
NSUInteger length = [fileData length];
NSUInteger index;

for (index = 0; index<length; index++) {
   char aByte = fileBytes[index];
   //Do something with each byte
}
```

Answer (score 2):

One of the simplest ways is to use [NSData getBytes:range:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1407224-getbytes?language=objc).

```
NSData *data = ...;
char buffer[numberOfBytes];
[data getBytes:buffer range:NSMakeRange(position, numberOfBytes)];
```

where position and length is the position you want to read from in NSData and the length is how many bytes you want to read. No need to copy.

Answer (score 1):

Alex [already mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12453078/how-to-read-bytes-from-nsdata/41079097#41079097) NSData getBytes:range: but there is also [NSData getBytes:length:](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdata/1411450-getbytes?language=objc) which starts from the first byte.

```
NSData *data = ...;
char buffer[numberOfBytes];
[data getBytes:buffer length:numberOfBytes];
```

Comment: Need to update your code snippet to read:    [data getBytes:buffer length:numberOfBytes];

Answer (score 0):

May way of doing that..
do not forget to free byte array after usage.

```
NSData* dat = //your code
NSLog(@"Receive from Peripheral: %@",dat);
NSUInteger len = [dat length];
Byte *bytedata = (Byte*)malloc(len);
[dat getBytes:bytedata length:len];
int p = 0;
while(p < len)
{
    printf("%02x",bytedata[p]);
    if(p!=len-1)
    {
     printf("-");
    }//printf("%c",bytedata[p]);
    p++;
}
printf("\n");
// byte array manipulation

free(bytedata);
```